# Intro Js multi page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, intro.js

I am working on and have implemented multipage but I need a small clarification regarding the multipage.

Current working :

- Step 1 : Next
- Step 2 : Next Prev
- Step 3 : Next Prev
- Step 4 : Next Prev
- Step 5 : NextPage

Clarification needed : ( Can i have multiple nextpage link in a page )

- Step 1 : Next
- Step 2 : Next Prev
- Step 3 : NextPage Prev
- Step 4 : Next Prev
- Step 4 : NextPage

Sorry, I am unable to explain things the better way.

Comment: With almost 1K rep you should know how to ask using a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the library, however the [multipage example](http://introjs.com/example/multi-page/index.html) on the project page uses the 'Done' button to include a next page button. You could use something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150318/firing-javascript-function-between-intro-js-steps) to change the 'Skip' button programmatically to your own 'Next Page' button, assuming you don't mind losing the ability to skip that particular step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intro.js 2 pages then return to home](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011744/intro-js-2-pages-then-return-to-home)